# marking a notebook with a special signature

Tags: notebooks

I have written my code and I want to pass it into publicity. How can I mark it with my signature? For instance, an inseparable text on the notebook or a password to run it or something else!
Is there any experience?

Comment: Code is text. You can't prevent a determined person from copying text, by retyping it if need be.

Comment: You can use tricks to make an encoded binary for code itself that Mathematica can run, but notebooks are plaintext and therefore anyone can go in and edit out anything you add. The best approach is probably to do what the open source community has done for years and put it on GitHub and publicly document that you made this object. People can steal it of course, but it gives a permanent record of provenance and for many things that’s enough.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions...I have seen GitHub...But I cannot understand the philosophy behind it.